# Git local clone doesn't have files

Tags: git, github

My git repo is missing files. They appear on github, but for some reason they are not in my local clone and they are not tracked as if I deleted them. `git status` appears as if nothing is wrong and there are not commits where I have deleted these files. It appears as if git thinks these files exist and they are unmodified. But the files don't actually exist on my file system.

How do you go about fixing this? Is there something I need to do to the `.git` directory?

Note: I have changes in my stash to unrelated files that do appears in my filesystem. I don't want to lose these stash changes.

EDIT: I've tried `git reset --hard` and variations of `git checkout`.

EDIT EDIT: `git ls-files` shows the files I want.

Comment: Have you maybe ignored them locally? You can check with `git ls-files -v | grep '^S'`

Comment: returned nothing when I ran that command.

Comment: Are you *sure*? Did you clone to a bare repository by mistake? The files are there, in the `.git` folder. It's the *working files* that are "missing", or rather, the files in the local repo were never checked out into the working folder

Comment: PS don't do ANYTHING to the `.git` folder. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried to clone again from GitHub to a different local directory and check if the files are present in that new clone then?

Comment: @anothernode I cloned to a new directory and the files on my branch are there. They are just in a weird state on my working repo. The `.git` must be in a weird state or something?

Comment: And you are sure your checked out working copy is the HEAD of the correct branch?

Comment: @anothernode positive I am on the HEAD of my current branch.

Comment: But when you say that those files do exist on GitHub, is that in the same branch there?

Answer (score 0):

From a pragmatic point of view, I'd suggest to pop your changes from the stash and then copy the affected files into a fresh clone of the repository.